# How to sort and remove the Duplicate entry in the file based on specific column

Tags: java, java-8, java-7

I have input file like below, input.txt

```
companyname,emailid,extenno,lastupdatedgmts  

Dell,jcrshan@gmail.com,985553434,2018-06-13 23:30:52.12
Dell,jcrshan@gmail.com,85553434,2018-06-14 23:30:52.12
IBM,ramesh@gmail.com,785553434,2018-06-15 23:30:52.12
UTO,benny@gmail.com,785553434,2018-06-16 23:30:52.12
```

I would like to do below actions on the above input file,

```
 1. sort the above file using emailed (second column) with ascending and lastupdatedgmts (fourth column) with descending
 2.remove duplicate based on emailid (second column)
```

expected output:

```
UTO,benny@gmail.com,785553434,2018-06-16 23:30:52.12
Dell,jcrshan@gmail.com,985553434,2018-06-14 23:30:52.12
IBM,ramesh@gmail.com,785553434,2018-06-15 23:30:52.12
```

Could you please help?

Comment: You've been around here a while, so should know the drill around code - can you post a [mcve] of what you've tried so far?

Comment: yes will post the code

Comment: Why is this tagged as both java-8 and java-7? It should only be tagged with the version you are using

Comment: am fine with either one of the version.. does it burdens you.

Comment: A solution I would try is to insert each row into a 2d list. Then you can use the `Collections.sort()` method on the list, using a custom `Comparator`. [see this for more details](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-sort-java-examples/) on custom comparators.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply.. if I have a million records then using collection would be advisable?

Comment: I don't see why not. If you're concerned about efficiency, the `Collections.sort()` method runs in a `nlogn` time complexity, and your custom comparator won't affect this.

Comment: Did you see that you got an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    String input = "companyname,emailid,extenno,lastupdatedgmts\n"
            + "\n"
            + "Dell,jcrshan@gmail.com,985553434,2018-06-13 23:30:52.12\n"
            + "Dell,jcrshan@gmail.com,85553434,2018-06-14 23:30:52.12\n"
            + "IBM,ramesh@gmail.com,785553434,2018-06-15 23:30:52.12\n"
            + "UTO,benny@gmail.com,785553434,2018-06-16 23:30:52.12\n";
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(input.split("\n"));
    list = list.subList(2, list.size()).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s->key(s), s->s, (s1,s2) -> s2)).values().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    list.sort((s1,s2)->key(s1).compareTo(key(s2)));;        
    System.out.println(list);
}

private static String key(String s) {
    return s.split(",")[1];
}
```